# Doing multiple REST requests or one request for multiple actions

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and trying to create a RESTful API
Now I have two resources that I want to get :

for example getting (Newspapers) and (Authors)

I have two choice but I don't know which of them is RESTful and does not break REST paradigm

First is to create a detail.php and have one keys called " which resource" then if I pass newspaper and authors it shows me newspapers details and authors :

```
http://local.rest/ci/api/detail/?res1=Newspaper&res2=authors
```

The second choice is to have two uri and two request to do this :

```
http://local.rest/ci/api/authors
http://local.rest/ci/api/newspapers
```

I know it sounds more clear but I think it is slower than first one.

Note: sometimes I need to call only one of them only.

Simply my question is : Is it required in REST to have one request per resource as?

Comment: I'd say write whatever interface you need to do it in one call and let the REST disciples worry if it's truly RESTful. Amen.

Comment: As a developer, you will many times encounter APIs that return responses that contain all kinds of related data. I've rarely encountered an API that makes you do multiple requests for related data, unless the first request is necessary to do the second request. APIs that make a developer work hard are APIs that suck. I know you want to try to impress yourself with how REST-awesome you can be, but REST was never meant to be a restriction and make things harder. If the common REST endpoint scheme doesn't quite fit what you or your API users will need, then it makes sense to allow other endpoints